# Генератор Entity

Tags: intellij-idea, entity

я знаю что вопрос не подходить к тематике [SO](http://stackoverflow.com). но все же давно использую *Idea* по работе много времени занимает генерирование `Entity`-ов в ручную, хотелось бы спросить есть ли какой то плагин для этого специально С `namedQuery` для *IDEA*? менять среду ради этого тоже не особо хочется. 
версия 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persistence => you persistence-unit name => (mouse right Click) => generating Persistence mapping => By DataBase Schema